# python error "TypeError : function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, linux, sockets

TypeError is appearing.
i want to make a working code so that i can submit it

i'm making a code
: client upload a file -> server get a file and save at server.

client is kali-linux, server is seed-ubuntu

STEP

1. Client
   echo "to be uploaded" > file.txt
   cat file.txt
2. Server
   python server.py
3. Client
   python client.py (ip addr of server) file.txt

Then, at server

connection from ~~~~
file name : file.txt
file created. file.txt

should come up,

And after this, at server
when i type cat file.txt
i should see the file_context.

but i only see the error.

this is server code

server.py

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 12345
s.bind (('',port))
s.listen(5)
print "Listening..."
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection from ', addr

    file_name = c.recv(1024)
    print "File name: ", file_name

    f= open(file_name, "w")
    file_context = f.write()
    f.close()

    c.recv(1024)
    print "File created!"
    c.close
```

and this is client code.

client.py

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
s.send(sys.argv[3])
data = s.send("")
f = open(sys.argv[3], "r")
f.read(data)
f.close()
s.close()
print 'uploaded!'
```

Comment: If you take a look at the traceback that's printed with the error, you should see the line on which it occurs. There, you're calling a function that expects a parameter, but provide one. If you want more detailed feedback, please post the actual taceback

Comment: ```file_context = f.write()``` should be ```f.write(file_context )```

Comment: And `f.read(data)` should be `data = f.read()`. You seem to have a backwards understanding of how read and write work.

Comment: `data = s.send("")` should be removed completely. Sending an empty string on a stream socket doesn't do anything.

Comment: Don't use the [tag:kali-linux] tag unless your issue directly involves the distro. The tag is a dumpster fire you don't want to be associated with, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

In the client, you're only sending the filename, not the file contents. You need to read from the file and send it on the socket. You also need a way to delimit the filename from the rest of the data; you could use a newline as the delimiter (this means you won't be able to send a file whose name includes newline, but it's adequate for a simple toy protocol).

When reading from a file or socket, you have to assign the result to a variable, not put the variable in the argument list of `read()` or `recv()`.

```
import socket
import sys
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s
    s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
    s.send(sys.argv[3] + "\n")
    with open(sys.argv[3], "r") as f
        data = f.read()
        s.send(data)
print 'uploaded!'
```

In the server, you need to read just a single line to get the filename. Sockets don't provide a `readline()` method, but there's a `makefile()` method that will create a file object that uses the socket as its underlying data source.

```
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s
    port = 12345
    s.bind (('',port))
    s.listen(5)
    print "Listening..."
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        cfile = c.makefile()
        print 'Connection from ', addr

        file_name = cfile.readline().strip()
        print "File name: ", file_name

        with open(file_name, "w") as f
            while True:
                data = cfile.read()
                if not data:
                    break
                f.write(data)

        print "File created!"
        close c
```